# Why aren't ::after and ::pseudo aligned with main element?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a simple burger menu using pseudo elements. However, I've came across two issues:

1. ::before and ::after are a little bit offsetted to the right (relative to the main element), which I have absolutely no idea why
2. when I don't set a height to `.minimize-menu div` it's automatically setted to 4px. Why does this happen (I mean, why not 5, 6 or 7px)?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.minimize-menu {
  /*     position: relative;
     */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*     top: 20px;
    right: 20px; */
  width: 15%;
  height: 25px;
}

.minimize-menu div {
  /*     position: relative;
     */
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.minimize-menu div::before,
.minimize-menu div::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.minimize-menu div::after {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="minimize-menu">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vowtz/deLqav9c/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, it's because you have a border around your `div` and your pseudo elements are *inside* of that. So you can set a negative left on your pseudo elements;

The second issue, is because your your `minimize-menu div` is a flex child, so the pseudo elements are essentially setting the parent box height to 6px because of their border sizes - since pseudo elements are children.

You can test by removing the pseudo elements and you'll see that the `div` is only 2px tall - because of its border.

I'm looking for the MDN that explains this so I can add it to the answer.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.minimize-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 15%;
  height: 25px;
}

.minimize-menu div {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.minimize-menu div::before,
.minimize-menu div::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.minimize-menu div::after {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="minimize-menu">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. It clarified many things to me. Just in case: setting .minimize-menu div {  box-sizing: border-box; } shouldn't avoid the misalignment?

Comment: You can set it to `border-box` if you want. That's more for how the *outside* of the element is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Your border is affecting a lot of things here giving which is why you have your 4px height.  Also you can have `position: relative` on your `.minimize-menu div` and `position: absolute;` on your psuedo elements.  And you will need to set a negative value for the `left` on the psuedos.  See here:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.minimize-menu {
  /*     position: relative;
     */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*     top: 20px;
    right: 20px; */
  width: 15%;
  height: 25px;
}

.minimize-menu div {
  /*     position: relative;
     */
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  position: relative;
}

.minimize-menu div::before,
.minimize-menu div::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.minimize-menu div::after {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="minimize-menu">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still getting the hang of positioning and box-sizing, its not full intuitive in my brain yet (but it's getting better). Kinda cumbersome for beginners, I think. Anyway, it makes much more sense right now.